# Create user with rails console returns nill for the email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Initially I don't have any users

Console

```
User.all
  User Load (4.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Then I create user from the interface, I get the same result if I create the user form the console.

```
User.all
  User Load (3.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, name: "Kevin Orfas", email: nil, created_at: "2015-02-12 16:54:39", updated_at: "2015-02-12 16:54:39", password_digest: "$2a$10$cYywG.DMlgMOnK1AjutfKepTgVo.0uR63W3k5yA7ZQH...">]>
```

Where should I focus to find the error?

UserController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

 def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

def new
   @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private
 def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
 end
end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, 
                  format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: You're going to have to post a bit more than that.  What do you put into the console to create the user?  Can you post your user model as well please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`downcase!` is a very weird method, very similar to `gsub!` in its weirdness - it returns `nil` if it doesn't change the initial string. Hence if your email is initially all lower case, you'll end up with `nil` after your `before_save` is executed. Change it to unbanged version and all will work:

```
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
```

or you can execute banged version directly on the string, without assignment:

```
before_save { self.email.downcase! }
```